# "Use of uninitialized value $_" warning with a Mojo::UserAgent non-blocking request

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo-useragent

I am trying to make a non-blocking request with
[`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent)
but when I run the code below I get

> Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string

on the `print` line.

How can I access `$_` inside the callback?

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new();

my @ids = qw( id1  id2 id3 );

foreach ( @ids ) {

    my $res = $ua->get('http://my_site/rest/id/'.$_.'.json' => sub {
        my ($ua, $res) = @_;
        print "$_ => " . $res->result->json('/net/id/desc'), "\n";
    });
}

Mojo::IOLoop->start unless Mojo::IOLoop->is_running;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_` is a special kind of variable where the value depends on the context. Inside the `foreach (@ip)` context it is set as an alias of specific item in the `@ip` array. But, the callback for `$ua->get(...)` gets not executed within the `foreach (@ip)` context and thus `$_` no longer is an alias into the `@ip` array.

Instead of using this special variable you need to use a normal variable scoped inside the `foreach (@ip)` loop, so that it can be bound to the subroutine (see also [What's a closure](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What's-a-closure%253f) in perlfaq7):

```
foreach (@ip) {
   my $THIS_IS_A_NORMAL_VARIABLE = $_;
   my $res= $ua->get( ...  => sub {
      my ($ua, $res) = @_;
      print  "$THIS_IS_A_NORMAL_VARIABLE =>" . $res->result->json('/net/id/desc'),"\n";
   });
}
```

Comment: Or simply `for my $id (@ids) { ...`, then you don't need to copy `$_` around.